# Var Keyword as optional parameter in c#

Tags: c#

Can we use var keyword in methods optional parameter? Keyword `var` should be initialised while declared. Can't I use this as a default parameter, because default parameter is initialised while declared.

For example:

```
public void MyMethod(string param, var optionalParam = string.Empty)
```

When  i try to do this then C# compiler is giving me an error, some one please explain.

Error:

> The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration
>
> Default parameter value for 'optionalParam' must be a compile-time constant

Comment: use dynamic keyword or object keyword

Comment: Show us the error you get.

Comment: Yes i know we can use dynamic or object, but i wanted to know why cant we use var over here.

Comment: `string.Empty` is not constant expression, so you can not use it as default value.

Comment: You can use `const` as an optional parameter, but `string.Empty` is *readonly* field. Try put it as `string optionalParam = ""`

Comment: Even if i use 5 as a value still i get the error. Its not about string.Empty.

Comment: @arun But you will get one less error, and thus less distraction from question you want to ask.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `var` keyword for optional parameters, mostly because you can't use the `var` keyboard for any parameters, even *non*-optional parameters. `var` can only be used for local method variables, not for method parameters, fields or any other place. The compiler error here is clear and unambiguous.

That said, you have a second error there, also explained by the compiler, that you can't set an optional parameter's default value to a non-const value. `string.Empty` is non-const. You'll have to use `null`, or explicitly `""` there.

Comment: I am sure it cannot be used but by definition it can be used right ?.  When i used an integer value i got this error : A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'var'.

Comment: No, it can never, ever be used in parameter declaration. That's what the C# spec says. That's what the compiler error says.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `String.Empty` is not declared with `const` so it can't be used as the default value for optional parameters anyway. Use `""` instead.

Though it seems perfectly okay to use `var` here, C# does not allow that.

According to the C# language specification section 10.6.1:

> Method parameters The parameters of a method, if any, are declared by
>   the method’s formal-parameter-list.

```
formal-parameter-list:     
    fixed-parameters
             fixed-parameters   ,   parameter-array     
        parameter-array
fixed-parameters:
         fixed-parameter
         fixed-parameters   ,   fixed-parameter
fixed-parameter:
     attributes(opt)   parameter-modifier(opt)   type   identifier   default-argument(opt) 
default-argument:     
    =  expression 
parameter-modifier:
         ref     
    out     
    this
parameter-array:     
    attributes(opt)   params   array-type   identifier
```

> The formal parameter
>   list consists of one or more comma-separated parameters of which only
>   the last may be a parameter-array. **A fixed-parameter consists of an
>   optional set of attributes (§17), an optional ref, out or this
>   modifier, a *type*, an identifier and an optional default-argument**. Each
>   fixed-parameter declares a parameter of the given type with the given
>   name. The this modifier designates the method as an extension method
>   and is only allowed on the first parameter of a static method.
>   Extension methods are further described in §10.6.9.

Note how it says `type` under the `fixed-parameter` grammar? That means it needs a type there, not `var`.

On the other hand, here is what the specs say about local variable declarations where `var` can be used.

> section 8.5.1 Local variable declarations

```
local-variable-declaration:     
    local-variable-type   local-variable-declarators
local-variable-type:     
    type
     var
local-variable-declarators:     
    local-variable-declarator     
    local-variable-declarators   ,   local-variable-declarator
local-variable-declarator:     
    identifier     
    identifier   =   local-variable-initializer
local-variable-initializer:
         expression     
    array-initializer
```

As you can see, for `local-variable-type`, it is either `type` or `var`. This shows that the specs treat `type` and `var` as different things. When it says `type` it must be a type, not `var`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned you cannot use `var` in the parameter list.

Now not having written the spec I can't tell you why you can't.  However there is a very good reason why you shouldn't.

The parameter list is used to tell whoever calls the method what to put in. As a result it should clearly state that. If you use `MyFunc(var param=Myconstant)` I have no idea what type param should be.

I would guess that is why `var` is only allowed in local variables. Since local variables are not meant to be used by any other part of the program its fine if they don't spell out explicitly what they are.